# Delta-matroids of embedded graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, definition, matroids

I'm not quite sure that I understand how we can construct corresponding delta-matroid for a given embedded graph. The text below is from the article "Delta-matroids and Vassiliev invariants" by S. Lando and V. Zhukov [[arXiv:1602.00027]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.00027):

[image: text]

Firstly, it seems to me that we may choose any path-connected set of edges to be a feasible set $\phi \in \mbox{Ф}$, but then there is a remark that for a plane graph $\phi$ is necessarily a spanning tree.

So, for example, suppose I have the following graph with numerated edges:

[image: plane_graph]

My question is may sets of edges $\{1\}$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$ and so on be treated as feasible sets or is there the only possibility to choose a set $\phi$ as $\{1,2,3,4\}$ since this graph has unique spanning tree that coincides with the graph itself?

Answer (score 0):

The wording in the paper you linked could be a little clearer, but the confusion lies in the fact that feasible sets have to be spanning. What they mean is $\phi \subset E(\Gamma)$ is feasible if the boundary of he embedding of all the vertices of $\Gamma$ together with $\phi$ is connected.